# How can I bulk update in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to update many documents in a single query, how can I update many documents in a single query such that I don't have to loop over a list and update each individually?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of operations that you want, and use a [bulkWrite](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/) (view the docs [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/)).

In that way you don't need to make a lot of request and get all the updates done. You can choose if you want the operations to be ordered or unordered and each type of operation has its own behavior. You can also choose which level of [write concern](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/write-concern/) you want.